# How can I create class in swift 3 for my custom message that conforms to JSQMessageData?

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am not familiar with Objective-C so I am not able to understand this.
My message structure is different than JSQMessage so I want to create my own class.

Here is my class

```
class ChatMessage:NSObject {

var createdAt:Double?
var createdName:String?
var createdUid:String?
var imageUrl:String?
var name:String?
var text:String?
var uColor:String?
var uid:String?
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're implementing this in Swift, and you want to make it usable within that framework, you should make your class conform to `JQMessageData`. You just need to implement the required methods and variables.

```
class ChatMessages: NSObject, JSQMessageData {

    // MARK: Required methods
    func senderId() -> String! {
        // your code here, return a unique ID for your sender
    }

    func senderDisplayName() -> String! {
        // your code here, return the display name of your sender
    }

    func date() -> Date! {
        // your code here, return your message date
    }

    func isMediaMessage() -> Bool {
        // your code here, return whether your message contains media
    }

    func messageHash() -> UInt {
        // your code here, return a unique identifier for your message
    }

    // MARK: Optional methods

    func text() -> String! {
        // your code here, return your message text
    }

    func media() -> JSQMessageMediaData! {
        // your code here, return your message media if required
    }

    // MARK: Other methods and variables
    // ...

}
```

Check the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/6.0-beta5/Protocols/JSQMessageData.html) for what to return in those methods.

Comment: Hey thanks.
I did this but it still says that class doesn't conform to protocol

Comment: @AbrarNiyazi hey, it looks like I was missing a method and some of the types were wrong. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @AbrarNiyazi Please accept my answer if it helped :)